# full template specialization not working: no instance of function template "mysort2" matches the specified type STLTests

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create full specialization of a function template:

```
#pragma once
#include <list>
template< template<typename T, typename A > typename C, typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T> >
void mysort2(C<T, A>& container)
{
    std::sort(container.begin(), container.end());
}
template<>
void mysort2< std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >, int, std::allocator<int> >(std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >& mylist)
{
    mylist.sort();
}
```

I get compile error messages:
1) no instance of function template "mysort2" matches the specified type
2) Error    C2912   explicit specialization 'void mysort2>,int,std::allocator<_Ty>>(std::list<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)' is not a specialization of a function template

Questions:

1) can this be done? How?
2) According to Scott Meyers, function template specialization should be discouraged. Shall this advice apply here?
3) What would be the recommended pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) can this be done? How?

Yes, by providing correct types explicitly:

```
template<>
void mysort2<std::list, int, std::allocator<int>>(std::list<int, std::allocator<int>>& c)
{
    c.sort();
}
```

or simply implicitly (as template arguments are deducible):

```
template<>
void mysort2(std::list<int, std::allocator<int>>& c)
{
    c.sort();
}
```

> 2) According to Scott Meyers, function template specialization should be discouraged. Shall this advice apply here?
>   3) What would be the recommended pattern?

I would say yes.
Simple overload does the job:

```
void sort2(std::list<int>& c) { c.sort(); }
```

And you cannot do partial specialization, but you could have additional overloads, as:

```
template <typename T, typename A>
void sort2(std::list<T, A>& c) { c.sort(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `mysort2` is a template parameter. Hence, you need to use `std::list`, not `std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >` in the specialization.

```
template<>
void mysort2< std::list, int, std::allocator<int> >(std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >& mylist)
{
    mylist.sort();
}
```